# export $PATH not working correctly on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: command-line, environment-variables

I have connected to remote Linux desktop (Ubuntu 13.10) using ssh command and try to run following command on remote desktop.  On my host machine I am using Ubuntu 12.04.

On remote desktop:

I have copy of FriendlyARM board's toolchain at '/home/linuxUser/FriendlyArm/opt/FriendlyARM/toolschain/4.5.1/' location.

I open a terminal set PATH environment variable by,

```
$ export PATH=/home/linuxUser/FriendlyArm/opt/FriendlyARM/toolschain/4.5.1/bin:$PATH
```

now try to run my hello.c program by

```
$ arm-linux-gcc hello.c
```

I got error:

```
-bash: /home/linuxUser/FriendlyArm/opt/FriendlyARM/toolschain/4.5.1/bin/arm-linux-gcc: No such file or directory
```

I run following command for some more information

```
$ echo $PATH

/home/linuxUser/FriendlyArm/opt/FriendlyARM/toolschain/4.5.1/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games

$ ls -l ~/FriendlyArm/opt/FriendlyARM/toolschain/4.5.1/bin/arm-linux-gcc

lrwxrwxrwx 1 linuxUser linuxUser 26 Sep 28  2010 /home/linuxUser/FriendlyArm/opt/FriendlyARM/toolschain/4.5.1/bin/arm-linux-gcc -> arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc

ls -l ~/FriendlyArm/opt/FriendlyARM/toolschain/4.5.1/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc

-r-xr-xr-x 2 linuxUser linuxUser 249588 Sep 24  2010 /home/linuxUser/FriendlyArm/opt/FriendlyARM/toolschain/4.5.1/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc
```

Comment: Did you try `/home/linuxUser/FriendlyArm/opt/FriendlyARM/toolschain/4.5.1/bin/arm-linux-gcc hello.c`

Comment: I tried that also but got same error.

Comment: Did you restart the system or logout and back in?

Comment: The program can't find a library it depends on.  Run `ldd ~/FriendlyArm/opt/FriendlyARM/toolschain/4.5.1/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc` to see what libraries it wants and can't find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not related to a `$PATH` error, on 13.10 you need to install the 13.04 `ia32-libs` package.

You can download the `ia32-libs` package from the [raring repository](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/amd64/ia32-libs/download).

Download it from a mirror and install it manually, then you should run the `arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc` executable.

```
sudo dpkg -i ./ia32-libs_20090808ubuntu36_amd64.deb
```